# System verilog simulation performance for uvm_hdl_read vs assign statement

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-dpi

I need to generate around 10,000 connectivity assertions to check that values driven at DUT interface at the beginning of simulation has reached (and is retained) at around 10,000 points inside the DUT throughout the simulation.
The 10k destination points inside DUT are available through xls, hence, if I can take the paths to  an array, I could write a single assertion property and instantiate it multiple times while iterating through the array.
What is the better approach here for simulation performance?

1. Using `assign` :

```
logic[7:0] dest_vals[10000];
assign dest_vals[0] = dut_path0.sig0; //This assignment code can be script-generated 
assign dest_vals[1] = dut_path1.sig1;
....
assign dest_vals[9999] = dut_path9999.sig9999;

property check_val(expected_val, dut_val);
 @(posedge assert_clk) expected_val == dut_val; 
endproperty

genvar i;
generate
for(i=0;i<9999;i++)
 assert property check_val(exp_val[i], dest_vals[i]);
endgenerate
```

2. Using `uvm_hdl_read` :

```
string dest_val_path[10000] = '{
"dut_path0.sig0",
"dut_path1.sig1",
....
"dut_path9999.sig9999"
};

property check_val(expected_val, dut_val);
 @(posedge assert_clk) expected_val == dut_val; 
endproperty

genvar i;
generate
for(i=0;i<9999;i++) begin

 initial forever begin
  @(posedge assert_clk);
  uvm_hdl_read(dest_val_path[i],dest_vals[i]);
 end

 assert property check_val(exp_val[i], dest_vals[i]);

end
endgenerate
```

Follow up question: Is there a way to change static array of size 10k to dynamic array/associative array/queue, so that if 10k destination points changes to 11k in future, array need not be re-sized manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `uvm_hdl_read` to access a signal by a string name is significantly slower than a direct hierarchical reference to a signal in an `assign` statement. A lot of code gets executed to lookup up that signal name in a string database and retrieve it from the simulator's internal database using the SystemVerilog's C based "VPI" routines. Plus, you can lose some optimizations because the value of the signal needs to be readily available at any point in time. In the case of the continuous `assign` statement, the simulator can work backwards and figure out it only needs the signal value on the `assert_clk` trigger.

How noticeable this performance difference is depends on a number of other factors

1. The overall size of the entire design's activity relative to additional code executed by `uvm_hdl_read`
2. How often the `assert_clk` triggers relative to the other activity in the design
3. How good a job you were able to limit VPI access to just the signals involved. Every signal you give VPI access to increases the size of the string database and prevents optimizations around that signal.

There is another option that does not involve `assign` statements or `generate` loops. You can use the `bind` construct to insert a module with your assertion. This works particularly well in your situation since you already have a script that produces the code for you.

```
module #(type T=logic [7:0]) mcheck(input logic clk, T expected_val, dut_val);
  property check_val;
   @(posedge clk) expected_val == dut_val; 
  endproperty
  assert property(check_val);
endmodule 

bind dut_path0 mcheck m(tb_path.assert_clk,tb_path.expected_val[0], sig0);
bind dut_path1 mcheck m(tb_path.assert_clk,tb_path.expected_val[1], sig1);
...
```

Note the port connections in the bind module are relative to the dut_path where `mcheck` is bound into.

Comment: I might need to use static array for expected_val though